# Android Kotlin add items to a ListView from a Spinner

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I am quite new to Android Development and Kotlin.
I created a spinner with some strings. After that, I'd like to add the selected item from the spinner and add it to a list and the last step being saving that list being stored as an object to be shown on another list (just the name) and if I click it, it will open the list I created previously.

I will show you the code and my layouts so you understand better what I've done and am missing

From here [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0nxV.png)(this is where the saved lists will go - activity_kit_list): 
I click NEW and go to another activity I have (but can't show because of my reputation) - activity_new_kit_list:
(This step is created)

Then, I click on the spinner and it shows the array I have (which is working). What I can't get my way around is how I make the rest of it working.

**NewKitListActivity:**

class NewKitListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Dumbell", "Punching Bag", "Yoga Ball", "Skipping Rope")
//var spinnerArray = arrayOf(DataService.kitList)



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_kit_list)



    val spinner = newKitItemSpinner
    val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray)
    //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter}}
```

Any pointers please?

P.S.: I have a DataService object that is storing an arrayOf. I tried to call it instead of typing those strings as you see but it didn't work (you can see the commented var there). Any reason why it didn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Joe may be this code will help you. What I did in this code

1. Set Empty Mutable List for storing selected item
2. Set spinner on Item Selected Listener
3. When I item selected that added in mutable list

   // Mutable List for storing selected items
           val selectedItems: MutableList? = null

   ```
        // Listen On select for spinner
               spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

                   //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
                   override fun onItemSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>, arg1: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

                      // Add selected item in Mutable List
                      selectedItems.add(spinnerArray[position])


                   }

                   override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {
                       // TODO: Auto-generated method stub


                   }

               }
   ```